# Search Date Range Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

How does one do an Instant Search query for a date range in Outlook, in order to look for emails between two dates?

This is answered all over the web, but none of the SE family came up in web search results.  And, only the more complicated versions of the question seem to appear when searching SE itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Outlook 2016, using date formats that are *appropo to your system* will work, provided they use slashes instead of hyphens.

```
received:yyyy/mm/dd..yyyy/mm/dd
```

or,

```
received:mm/dd/yyyy..mm/dd/yyyy
```

will limit emails received in the given time period, inclusive of the start and end dates.

Comment: So you have found the solution, or this is just a solution sharing? Feel free to correct me if I've misunderstood something.

Comment: @SteveFan I'm not sure what you're asking.  I had a question that didn't seem to be asked here, so I looked up the answer myself.  The SE family allows you to create a question, and check a checkbox to immediately answer the question.  I thought the idea was that if someone else comes along with the same question, they can find both, with opportunities for people to give corrections and even better answers.

Comment: Oh that's great, thank you for sharing the solution :-) Just wanted to make sure that I was not misunderstanding anything.

Comment: [More keywords are available](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da) such as from, about, subject, hasattachment, etc.

Comment: @EndyTjahjono at first I didn't think the link was pertinent to the question until I scrolled down.  `received:last week` and so forth are definitely pertinent.  Thanks!